# Difference of two self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have the following question regarding self-adjoint operator and I am not quite sure about its answer. Let  $A_{n}: \operatorname{Dom}(A_{n})\subset H \rightarrow H$ be symmetric operator densely defined on a Hilbert space $H$ that has some self-adjoint extension due to the so-called Von Neumann theorem.  Consider another operator   $B_{c}: \operatorname{Dom}(B_{c}) \subset H \rightarrow H$ be symmetric operator densely defined on a Hilbert space $H$ which also has some self-adjoint extension, again due to Von Neumann theorem. In both cases, the dimension of the deficiency spaces is $n_{+}=n_{-}=1$. On the other hand, we can also write  $B_{c}=A_{n}+ \delta B_{c}$ or equivalently, $\delta B_{c}=B_{c}-A_{n}$. I know that in principle  $\delta B_{c}$ does not necessarily have a self-adjoint extension. Questions that I am interested in :

1-How can I prove that  $\delta B_{c}$ is not self-adjoint?
Or what are the conditions to become self-adjoint?

2-Let us suppose that $\delta B_{c} \phi=0$ with $\phi \in \operatorname{Dom}(B_{c})$. Can I conclude that the spectrum of the operator $B_{c}$ must be equal to the spectrum of $A_{n}$? So, in the end, both problems are equivalent. Is this correct?

In order to be much clear, I will re-write this problem in another way. Let us consider that we have two problems associated with Schrodinger-like equations in different patches of coordinates:

1-The  first problem is given by  an operator $A_{n}: Dom (A_{n}) \subset H \rightarrow H$ densely defined on a Hilbert space and its domain is given by $Dom(A_{n})= \{ \phi \in H^{2}(0, \infty)/ \phi(0)=\phi'(0)=\phi(\infty)=\phi'(\infty)=0  \}$ being $H^{2}$ the usual sobolev space and the prime stands for derivative with respect to the coordinate $x_{n} \in [0, \infty)$.

The first operator is given by   $A_{n}= -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}_{n}} + V_{n}[x_{n}]$  and the potential energy operator is

$V=\frac{e^{x_{n}/r_{0}}(9e^{x_{n}/r_{0}} -10)}{4r^{2}_{0}(9e^{x_{n}/r_{0}} -1)^{2}}$.

Here $r_{0}$ is just a positive constant.  This operator has some self-adjoint extensions due to Von Neumann theorem. The dimension of the deficiency subspaces  is $n_{+}=n_{-}=1$. The map between both subspaces $N_{+}$ and $N_{-}$ is given by an isometry and can be parametrized by a complex number.

2-The second  problem is given by  another operator $B_{c}: Dom (B_{c}) \subset H \rightarrow H$ densely defined on a Hilbert space and its domain is given by $Dom(B_{c})= \{ \psi \in H^{2}(-\infty, 0)/ \psi(0)=\psi(-\infty)=\psi'(-\infty)=0  \}$ being $H^{2}$ the usual sobolev space again and the prime stands for derivative with respect to another coordinate $x_{c} \in (-\infty, 0)$.

The second operator is given by   $B_{c}= -\frac{(e^{-\mid b \mid x_{c}}-1)}{r^{2}_{0}b^{2}}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}_{c}} + V_{c}[x_{c}]$, where the potential energy operator is $V=2\frac{e^{-\mid b\mid x_{c}}}{r^{2}_{0}}$. Here $b<0$.  Besides,  the second operator also has some self-adjoint extensions due to Von Neumann theorem. The dimension of the deficiency subspaces  is $n_{+}=n_{-}=1$. The map between both subspaces $N_{+}$ and $N_{-}$ is given by an isometry and can be paramtrized by a complex number.

3-The map between the $x_{n}$ coordinate and the $x_{c}$ coodinate is given by $x_{c}=\frac{1}{\mid b \mid} \log (1- e^{-\frac{x_{n}}{r_{0}}})$, where $x_{n} \in [0, \infty)$ and $x_{c} \in (-\infty,0)$.

4-I started from the $B_{c}$ operator and used the chain rule to connect with the $A_n$ operator. I also had to add and substruct a the term $V_{n}$.

5-The rest of the problem is the same thing that I posted before.

Any help with these issues would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your $\delta$? And the significance of the subscripts on $A_n$ and $B_c$? And why/how do you know $B_c=A_n+\delta B_c$? Doesn't this give a relation? And do you know anything about the relationship of the domains?

Comment: Hello Paul, I added more information about the problem. Here $\delta$ is just a notation does not have any special meaning. The relation between the domain is mentioned above.